# how to change transport config when create a email template in Laravel 7?

Tags: php, laravel

sometimes, we use our custom platform to send emails, and we need to change some config after create an email template.

here is some code to create email template.

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class ResetPassword extends Mailable implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $token;
    public $url;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        $this->token = $token;
        $this->url = $token;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $subject = sprintf("[%s] %s", setting('app_name'), __('Password Reset Request'));

        return $this->subject($subject)->markdown('mail.reset-password');
    }
}
```

```
// test to send an email
Mail::to( User::find(1) )->send( new UserRegistered( User::find(1)  ) );
```

when we use 3rd platform like Mailgun,

how should we access the transport method, like setKey,

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Mail/Transport/MailgunTransport.php#L169

Thank you.

Comment: You should not be able to access the transport directly, instead of invoking set methods directly it’s configured through configuration files like .env. Key on your example is not part of an email template, but rather part of connection settings for Mailgun, therefore there is no need to change it during dispatching of emails through email provider. You can set Key via example provided in [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/mail#driver-prerequisites)

Comment: Thank you, Daniel, for Changing key just an example to show what I want to do,

In fact, I extend mail mange lib for using another platform, and there is a param called template-id, I need to change it every time when I create an email template.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have setup `Mailgun` on their website. Now you need to follow the below steps to send mail using `Mailgun`

**Step1:**  Change mail driver in your `.env` file will look like this:

**Change**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
```

to

```
MAIL_DRIVER=mailgun
```

**Step2:** Add `Mailgun` credentials to your app services config file i.e `config/services.php`.

```
<?php

return [

    'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => 'your_domain_name',
        'secret' => 'your_mailgun_secret',
    ],

    ];
```

Comment: yes , thank you for your response,

how should I change other params after I creating an email template, here is some code like 

```
'mailgun' => [
        'domain' => 'your_domain_name',
        'secret' => 'your_mailgun_secret',
        'template' => tmp_id',
    ],
```

how should we change the template variable?

there is a method in mailgun transport lib exactly called ** setKey **, but I have no idea when and how to access this method.

Comment: any improvement?